# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(x \int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Use L'Hospital rule compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \left(x \int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right)$$

my attempt:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\displaystyle \left(\int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right)} x$$ ($0/0$ form)

$$=\lim _{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x/x^2}{-x^2}=-1$$

Comment: Use integration by parts on the integral and the answer should not be difficult to obtain. You have a mistake in the use of L'Hospital's Rule,the derivative of integral is $-(\cos x) /x^{2}$ so the answer should be $1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh..yes i got this idea  but it some what difficult

Comment: Now you have another mistake. The denominator should be $1/x$ instead of $x$ and the form is $\text{anything} /\infty$ and not $0/0$. L'Hospital's Rule is applicable and answer is immediately arrived at as $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you've almost got it! So you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\displaystyle \left(\int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right)}{(1/x)}$$
Which is a good step. Then you apply L'Hopital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left(\int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

Observe that $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int ^1_x \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right) = -\frac{d}{dx} \left(\int ^x_1 \frac{\cos t }{t^2} \, dt\right) = -\frac{\cos x }{x^2}$ and $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$. This gives,

$$\lim _{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x}{-x^2} \large/\frac{-1}{x^2} = \lim _{x\to0^+} \cos x = 1$$

So just a couple mistakes on your part. The first was writing $x$ instead of $1/x$ in the denominator, and the second when you applied the FTC to the integral which put you off by a minus sign.

Comment: @AlkaKadri...thank you

Comment: No problem! Note that there's the technicality of showing that $\int_x^1 \frac{\cos t}{t^2}\ dt \to\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$, but that's not too hard to see I think.

Comment: @AlkaKadri: that technicality is not needed. See my comments to question. L'Hospital's Rule is applicable when denominator tends to $\infty$ and in that case there is no need to check numerator.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That is false. You need an indeterminate form to apply L'Hopital's rule. Consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$. Clearly the limit is equal to 0, but if we naiively apply L'Hopital's because the denominator tends to infinity then we get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$, which does not exist.

Comment: You need to learn a bit more about this infamous L'Hospital's Rule. Check the proof in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) where it shows that the rule applies to the form $\text{anything} /\infty$. Also the rule works only when the limit of $f'(x) /g'(x) $ exists finitely or infinitely. In the example you gave the rule fails because the limit of $f'(x) /g'(x) $ does not exist.

Comment: It is because of the fact that most people (including you) are unaware of the exact hypotheses under which L'Hospital's Rule works that the rule should be avoided in preference to other methods like Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh very interesting. It's surprising how many years one can go without seeing that proof (my bad). I suppose that in this case we indeed have something of the form $x \to c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, whereas the counterexample up there with $x \to \infty$ that I've kept back of my mind is another beast entirely. Thank you for this!

Comment: Don't worry. You are not alone in this situation. The root cause of all this are crappy textbooks which don't highlight the intricacies of L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Note that using integration by parts we have $$\int_{x} ^{1}\frac{\cos t} {t^{2}}\,dt=\frac{\cos x} {x} - \cos 1-\int_{x}^{1}\frac{\sin t} {t} \, dt$$ and multiplying by $x$ and taking limit as $x\to 0^{+}$ we can see that the limit is $1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh...how did u get 1

Comment: @suresh: When you multiply by $x$ the first term becomes $\cos x$ and it tends to $1$. Rest of the terms have $x$ as a factor so tend to $0$.

Comment: You forgot to point out that $\int_x^1 \sin{t}/t \,\mathrm{d}t$ converges as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh..thank you too i got it

Comment: @tristan: there is nothing to converge as the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin t} {t} \, dt$ exists as a Riemann integral and hence the function $g(x) =\int_{x} ^{1}\frac{\sin t} {t} \, dt$ tends to $g(0)$ as $x\to 0^{+}$.

Comment: Yes of course, but I wouldn't say this is completely trivial since one has to first extend the function $t\mapsto \sin{t}/t$ by continuity at $t=0$.

Comment: @tristan: the function under consideration is bounded in $[0,1]$ and has only one discontinuity at $0$ so it is Riemann integrable. But yes yes it is not trivial to notice this fact. I would consider is somewhere between trivial and non-trivial I terms of difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\bracks{x\int_{x}^{1}{\cos\pars{t} \over t^{2}}\,\dd t} & =
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\bracks{%
x\int_{x}^{1}{\cos\pars{t} - 1 \over t^{2}}\,\dd t +
x\int_{x}^{1}{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{x \to 0^{\large +}}\bracks{%
x\int_{x}^{1}{\cos\pars{t} - 1 \over t^{2}}\,\dd t - x + 1} =\bbx{1}
\end{align}

Comment: This one is perhaps even simpler than my answer (although it uses similar idea). +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree. They are quite close. $\left.\substack{{\Huge\bullet}\\ {\Huge \smile}}\right\}$